# M/M/c non-preemptive priority queue with batch service

Tags: reference-request, queueing-theory

I am looking for work on bulk service queueing models with non-preemptive priority. It seems to me that there is a lot done in terms of bulk arrivals but I cannot find a paper that focuses on bulk service AND non-preemptive priority. Could anyone recommend something along these lines?

For example, [Krishna, Nadarajan and Kandasamy (1991)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030505489390088Z) analyse a non-preemptive priority multiserver queueing system consisting of two types of customer units with Poisson arrival and exponential service time distribution is analysed. The lower priority units are served in batches according to a general bulk service rule. The higher priority units have nonpreemptive priority over lower priority units. The higher priority units are served singly.

Has there been work done in a similar setting but when both priority units are serviced according to a bulk service rule?

I would greatly appreciate any references or ideas, thanks in advance!